# cin crashing my program after 12 for loop iterations?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, crash, cin

I've never posted here before but I'm really stuck so I thought i'd give it a try. I've been working on this code for a while, The aim is to input a few students with their marks and to output them into tables with averages and totals. I was given a file like this:

```
15
Albert Einstein 52 67 63
Steve Abrew 90 86 90 93
David Nagasake 100 85 93 89
Mike Black 81 87 81 85
Andrew Van Den 90 82 95 87
Joanne Dong Nguyen 84 80 95 91
Chris Walljasper 86 100 96 89
Fred Albert 70 68
Dennis Dudley 74 79 77 81
Leo Rice 95
Fred Flintstone 73 81 78 74
Frances Dupre 82 76 79
Dave Light 89 76 91 83
Hua Tran Du 91 81 87 94
Sarah Trapp 83 98
```

my problem is that when I am inputting the names the program crashes after Fred Flinstone, I know its not a problem with the formatting of the next name (Frances Dupre) because when i moved him up the list it read it fine.

I have located where the program is crashing with 'cerr' outputting at different stages of the read process and it crashes when it is trying to read in Frances's marks.

**a1main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numStds;
    cin >> numStds;

    cerr << endl << "Num Stds: " << numStds << endl;

    Student std[numStds+1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numStds; i++)
    {
        std[i].readData();
        std[i].printStudent();  
    }

    // delete [] std;

    return 0;
}
```

**student.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {

    private:

        char* name;
        int mark[4];
        int num;

    public:

        Student();
        ~Student();

        void readData();
        void printStudent();
        float getTotal();
        float getAverage();
};
```

**student.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student()
{
        name = new char;
        mark[0] = 0;
        mark[1] = 0;
        mark[2] = 0;
        mark[3] = 0;
        num = 0;
}

Student::~Student()
{
    // Doesn't work?

    // delete name;
}

void Student::readData()
{   
    int l = 0;

    // Reading the Name
    cin >> name;        // Read in the first name
    l = strlen(name);   // get the strlength
    name[l] = ' ';      // Putting a space between the first and last name
    cin >> &name[l+1];  // Read in the last name

    cerr << endl << "I have read the name!" << endl;

    // Checking if there is a third name
    if(cin.peek() == ' ')
        cin >> ws;      // checking and navigating past the whitespace

    char next = cin.peek();
    if( isalpha(next) )     // Checking whether the next cin is a char
    {
        l = 0;
        l = strlen(name);
        name[l] = ' ';
        cin >> &name[l+1];
    }

    cerr << "I've checked for a third name!" << endl;

    // Reading in the marks
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // Checks if the next cin is a newline
        if (cin.peek() == '\n')
            break;

        cin >> mark[i];
    }

    cerr << "I've read in the marks!" << endl;

    //cerr << endl << "I have read " << name << "'s marks!" << endl << endl;

    for(int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
    {   
        if(mark[m] != 0)
        {
            num++;
        }
    }

    cerr << "I've incremented num!" << endl << endl;
}

// Function for error checking
void Student::printStudent()
{
    cout << endl << "Student Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Mark 1: " << mark[0] << endl;
    cout << "Mark 2: " << mark[1] << endl;
    cout << "Mark 3: " << mark[2] << endl;
    cout << "Mark 4: " << mark[3] << endl;
    cout << "num marks: " << num << endl << endl; 
}

float Student::getTotal()
{}
float Student::getAverage()
{}
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong? thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure but your read function is too complicated for what it does. Why bother peeking over the same data entry? Get the entire line and parse it or pass the string to a function that parses and populates students why don't ya?

Comment: i'm not sure, that's just the original path that i'm went down to retrieve the data, do you think it would be better if i broke it up into different functions i.e. readName(), readMark()... so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never allocating memory to store the student names.

In your Student constructor, add this code:

```
name = new char[100]; // allows names up to 100 characters long
```

and uncomment this line in the destructor:

```
delete[] name;
```

You could also make the code more sophisticated and robust by measuring the name length and allocating the correct size, or use std::string as suggested below.

Comment: Or just use `std::string` to avoid these mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) but in my assignment it's specified that  "You need to use dynamic memory allocation to store student’s name for this task. Make
sure there is no memory leak. Do not forget to include namespace in your program files." is that still allocating the memory dynamically?

Comment: Also could anyone explain why it worked up until specifically the 12th name every time? thanks :), I'm just trying to get a better understanding of why it's done what it did.

Comment: when you are writing to unallocated memory addresses the behaviour is undefined. you could compile it on a different machine and get different behaviour. however, you were allocating a single char for each student so there would have been some memory allocated, and the 12th name just happened to be the first one where you wrote to an address not allocated by your process.

Comment: if you want to use dynamic allocation and don't want to use std::string, I think it's better to use a local variable e.g. char tempname[100] inside your readData() function, read the name into it and allocate name = new char[strlen(tempname)+1], then copy tempname into it. then you only allocate the memory you need

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense, that would mean i would allocate the memory in the readData() function rather than in the constructor?